# Hadoop Job execution

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run an Djikstra's Algorithm in Hadoop using the MapReduce Framework. I was successful in executing a sample wordcount program using the following command:

**./bin/hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.9.jar wordcount /examples/jverne /examples/jverne/output**

Now i want to execute my Djikstra.java using the above command. I have created the class files of my application using netbeans. According to me the class files should be placed in **/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.9.jar** as it contains the class files of wordcount program. I am not sure how should i modify the command so that it will execute my class files and execute my djikstra algorithm.

Any help will be appreciated.

Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Any hadoop job can be executed using the below command

`./bin/hadoop jar /path/to/your/jar yourMainClass /path/to/input /path/to/output`

Now, to run your job, create a jar of your code, give the path to the jar and the main class name, also specify the input as well as output.